# defining a custom operator in terms of other operators?

Tags: swift

As a way to learn Swift, I've been implementing some functional operators in a playground. I'm a little frustrated about how verbose I had to be while defining a composition (`<<`) and reverse-composition (`>>`) operator, and I was wondering if there is an idiomatic way to do this in swift:

```
infix operator << {associativity right}
func << <T,U,N>(f: N -> U, g: T -> N) -> (T -> U) {
    return { f(g($0)) }
}
```

I also have a flip function:

```
func flip<A, B, T>(f: (A,B) -> T) -> (B, A) -> T {
    return { (b: B, a: A) -> T in return f(a, b) }
}
```

I would like to define a reverse-composition operator (`>>`) in terms of flipping my composition operator, but I've had no luck thus far. In contrast, this seems ugly to me:

```
infix operator >> {associativity left}
func >> <T, U, N>(g: T -> N, f: N -> U) -> (T -> U) {
    return f << g
}
```